# php get message from rabbitmq error

Tags: php, rabbitmq

My amqp extension version is 1.0.1 & AMQP protocol version is 0-9-1

get messages from queue :

```
<?php
try {
$conn = new AMQPConnection() ;
$conn->setLogin('guest') ;
$conn->setPassword('guest') ;
$conn->connect() ;
if ($conn->isConnected()) {
    $channel = new AMQPChannel($conn) ;
    if ($channel->isConnected())
    {
        $queue = new AMQPQueue($channel) ;
        $queue->setName('test_queue') ;
        $queue->setFlags(AMQP_DURABLE | AMQP_AUTODELETE) ;
        $queue->declare() ;
        $messages = $queue->get(AMQP_AUTOACK) ;
        print_r($messages->getBody()) ;
    }
} else {
    echo "connect failure ... " ;
}
$conn->disconnect() ;} catch (Exception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage() ;}?>
```

and it doesn't work ..

```
Server channel error: 406, message: PRECONDITION_FAILED - parameters for queue 'test_queue' in vhost '/' not equivalent
```

Answer (score 9):

It seems to me that the queue already exists and it was declared (created) previously with different parameters in the vhost. Queues need to be declared exactly with the same parameters every time (or deleted and recreated with the desired parameters). Try deleting the queue via the management plugin (http://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html) and then running your script again

Answer (score 1):

If your queue has already been created you don't need to create it (using 'declare' method) and bind with exchange once again. IMHO you shouldn't do it as a) these actions require administrative privileges b) it's enough to to it only once c) you might not have got administrative rights on production and your code would be broken.
I believe it's better to create and bind all required queues with management console or any other tool you like and then receive messages this way

```
// consider using connection more than once. that's only for illustration purposes.
$connection = new AMQPConnection([ put your credentials here ]);
$connection->connect();
if(!$connection->isConnected()) {
    throw new Exception('Connection failed.');
}

$chnlObj = new AMQPChannel($connection);
$queObj  = new AMQPQueue($chnlObj);
$queObj->setName('yourQueueName');
echo $queObj->get(AMQP_AUTOACK)->getBody();

// consider using connection more than once. that's only for illustration purposes.
$connection->disconnect();
```